# How to send a Greeting Message with a Discord Bot - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to develop a Discord bot and I want it to send a greeting message when someone is added to the server. 
I'm getting this error :

```
/perso-workspace/discordtest/index.js:31
guild.defaultChannel.send(`Bienvenue ${member.user} sur mon serveur Discord !  `).catch(console.error);
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Client.bot.on.member (/home/spoisson/Documents/perso-workspace/discordtest/index.js:31:26)
    at Client.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Guild._addMember (/home/spoisson/Documents/perso-workspace/discordtest/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Guild.js:1192:19)
    at GuildMemberAddHandler.handle (/home/spoisson/Documents/perso-workspace/discordtest/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/GuildMemberAdd.js:12:13)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/home/spoisson/Documents/perso-workspace/discordtest/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/home/spoisson/Documents/perso-workspace/discordtest/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/home/spoisson/Documents/perso-workspace/discordtest/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/spoisson/Documents/perso-workspace/discordtest/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Receiver._receiver.onmessage (/home/spoisson/Documents/perso-workspace/discordtest/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:137:47)
```

Here is my code :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()


bot.on('ready', function(){
    console.log('I am ready to learn !')
})

bot.on('message', function (message){
    if (message.content === '!ping') {
        message.channel.send('Pong !')
    }
})

bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    let guild = member.guild;
    console.log('Guild is ' + guild + ' and member is ' + member.user)
    guild.defaultChannel.send(`Bienvenue ${member.user} sur mon serveur Discord !  `).catch(console.error);
});

bot.login('i_set_my_token_here')
```

I already tried different tutorials on YouTube or whatever, but I don't understand the difference I have with the guys I'm watching. 
The first command ( !ping ) is working great. I managed to set an activity to my bot.

I saw that `defaultChannel` is deprecated, but I didn't find anything that can match what I want.

Can anyone guide me to the answer / correction of this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New discord servers no longer have a default channel, so `Guild#defaultChannel` became deprecated and returns  undefined for newer guilds.

If you want the bot to just find a channel by name, you can use:

```js
guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'general-chat');
```

You could also iterate through a list of possible channel names to allow more channels, or you could have a configuration that sets the log channel.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your hint !
I found out that I can get the channel ID by enabling Developer Mode on my Discord Appearence. I did the same thing but using the channel.id and it worked ! 
Here's what I changed :
`bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    let guildChannel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.id === '562256947764527115');
    if(!guildChannel) {
        return
    }
    if(guildChannel.type != "text"){
        return
    }
    guildChannel.send('Bienvenue ${member.user} sur mon serveur Discord !').catch(console.error)
});`